# Request parameter in jsp page

Tags: struts2

Im setting my parameter in my jsp like so -

```
<s:url id="open" action="viewEvent">
                    <s:param name="eventName" value="eventName" />
                </s:url> <sj:a href="%{open}" targets="eventSearchResultsDiv">Open</sj:a>
```

How can I access this parameter in my jsp page. This does'nt seem to be working -

```
<s:property value="eventName" />
```

Although this works  - `<%= request.getParameter("eventName") %>`

Thanks

Comment: Does your action have a getter and setter for eventName?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[The documentation](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/jsp.html) says :

> Assuming there's a request parameter myParameter (e.g. http://host/myApp/myAction.action?myParameter=one).

```
<s:property value="%{#parameters.myParameter}" />
```

Comment: That was actually an answer, not a comment. The line which you've posted (and this line) are comments :) (they are posted by clicking `add comment`; answers are posted by the answer input box at the very bottom of the question)

Comment: Please note that #parameters.myParameter is actually an array, as I've found out today. It took me some time, so I share it. If you want to get the length of the parameter, #parameters.myParameter.length() will not work, but #parameters.myParameter[0].length() will.

Answer (score 3):

There are some implicit objects in JSP pages that provide access to this sort of information.  The one you are looking for is param.  If you were writing jstl with c:out for example you could do:

`<c:out value="${param.eventName}"/>`

Or in your example:

```
<s:url id="open" action="viewEvent">
    <s:param name="eventname" value="${param.eventName}"/>
</s:url>
```