# How to access query string using Struts 2 tags from a JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, tags, struts2, query-string

I am redirecting to a JSP that has to print the whole incoming query string. Like in this other question, [Request parameter in jsp page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874820/request-parameter-in-jsp-page), I do not want to access one parameter but the whole query string which I would accomplish in a scriptlet like: <%= request.getQueryString() %>

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure, but `{pageContext.request.queryString}` could help.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the paramater object by `OGNL` stack value `#parameters`

http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/ognl-basics.html

If you want to iterate it, you can do something like ( this example create hidden input for each param)

```
<s:iterator value="#parameters" var="param">
    <s:hidden name="%{#param.key}" value="%{#param.value}" />                 
</s:iterator>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can user s:iterator tag in struts2 and you can get your string value in Jsp by OGNL lang which is supported by Struts2 without writing code in Scriptlet.

Please check below links for your reference.

http://www.vaannila.com/struts-2/struts-2-example/struts-2-ognl-expression-language-example-1.html
http://www.vaannila.com/struts-2/struts-2-example/struts-2-iterator-tag-example1.html